# Android TextView autoLink in an app widget

Tags: android, textview, android-appwidget, autolink

**I have an app widget with a `TextView` in it. I set its android:autoLink property to "web" so that the links can be clicked to launch them in browser. 
The links become clickable alright, but when I click on them an exception is thrown while opening the browser Activity.**

```
10-31 01:27:56.155: E/Nova.AppWidget(9427): com.capturekenya/.CaptureWidgetProvider v1.0 (1): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
10-31 01:27:56.155: E/Nova.AppWidget(9427):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1026)
10-31 01:27:56.155: E/Nova.AppWidget(9427):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1013)
10-31 01:27:56.155: E/Nova.AppWidget(9427):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
10-31 01:27:56.155: E/Nova.AppWidget(9427):     at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:64)
10-31 01:27:56.155: E/Nova.AppWidget(9427):     at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
```

**This is the TextView in the widget**

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/notification_textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/calendar_textView"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:autoLink="web"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/notification"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="12dp" />
```

Comment: Please add your code, and see if it relates to this https://coderwall.com/p/cg_efa?i=1&p=1&q=author%3Aldurazo&t%5B%5D=ldurazo

Comment: If you create a widget and have a TextView with with android:autoLink="web" then Set the text to something with a URL,the links will be colored but if the user clicks on the URL,you get the exception android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: I meant more code, where is the textview? over an adapter? outside an activity?

Answer (score 2):

On your method `getView(...)` inflate your view like this:

```
 LayoutInflater.from(YOUR_ACTIVITY_INSTANCE).inflate(R.layout.layout_with_text_view_autolink, parent, false);
```

Comment: No need to change getView, just pass the activity as context to the widget

Answer (score 1):

well,  this question result from URLSpan onClick

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getURL());
    Context context = widget.getContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, context.getPackageName());
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

if widget.getContext() is not instance of activity , intent must add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag ; we cannot add code here,so we shall make widget.getContext() return activty instance,

LayoutInflater.from(  activityInstance  ).inflate(R.layout.xxx,null); or new View( activityInstance)..

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution in case you are from a class that extends from BaseAdapter

from class MainActivity:

```
mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

from class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter

```
LeDeviceListAdapter(Activity activity) {
        beacons = new ArrayList<>();
        mInflator = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```